# Whitespace on Line 1 html caused by php function

Tags: php, html, whitespace

I have a php function in an include which is called to create my html head. The php include code begins with the following.

```
<?
function makeHead($title, $description, $keywords, $canonical, $author, $headextras, $robots = "index, follow"){
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The function is causing my html documents to be created with line 1 empty.

I have tried to remove all space. Like the following code example but without success

```
<? function makeHead($title, $description, $keywords, $canonical, $author, $headextras, $robots = "index, follow"){ ?><!DOCTYPE html>
```

I have searched for an answer, but I can only find articles relating to errors caused by whitespace. No errors are being generated in my problem. Could someone enlighten me as to where this blank html line is coming from?

Comment: Check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what I should be 'trimming'